# Dragon ball super timeline

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-series

The dragon ball super anime started last week.

I'm wondering when this takes place.
I know it takes place after the defeat of buu, like a few months or something.

But with the releases of the movies I'm wondering where does those fit in?
Can anybody answer me this?